# I can't connect asp.net VB with SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I've been tried to connect asp.net Webform aspx.vb whith sql server,but problem is when I wrote this code `Dim cn As New SqlConnection(con)` it error on `con`, I try to find out why it doesn't work.

> Error Message `con is not declared it may inaccessible sue to its protection level`

My Web.config code

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="connection"
  connectionString="Data Source=HOUCHANDARA;Initial Catalog=website;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My Module code

```
Imports System.Configuration

Public Module Connection
  Public con As String =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connection").ConnectionString
End Module
```

My aspx.vb code

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class HomePage
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection(con)
    If Not IsPostBack Then
      Try
        cn.Open()
        MsgBox("connect")
      Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("faild")
      End Try
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Include the error message that you get on con.

Comment: Once you figure out how to open your connection you need to add a FINALLY block in your code to close and destroy the connection object so it releases the connection back to the pool.

Comment: And the error is? Catching an exception without showing the error message is a bit useless. Also, remember that when you run this code in the  IIS context, the current user is the one used to start the IIS service. It need to have permissions to open Sql Server

Comment: 'con' is not declared it may inaccessible sue to its protection level

Comment: I'm no VB expert but shouldn't it be `Dim cn As New SqlConnection(Connection.con)`

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection(Connection.con)
```

apart from that, note that [`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is also cached. So there is no performance gain in using that "global" variable. You should also use the `Using`-statement for the connection to ensure that it gets disposed/closed as soon as possible even on error.